# Does O365 Unified API support Differential Query like AAD Graph does

Tags: office365

Found the Differential Query Console example here: 
  https://github.com/AzureADSamples/ConsoleApp-GraphAPI-DiffQuery-DotNet)

And it works fine against AAD.  But am not able to get it to work with new O365 Unified API, or find any mention of support for the differential query feature in the new Unified API docs.  There is a Sync action for Calendars.  By omision, am I to assume that is the only entity that can be synced?

1. Does the new Unified API support differential query?
2. If so, on what entities?  And, any hints on how to fix the example.
3. If not now, is it planed for the future?

Thanks in advance,
Randy

Comment: Nothing is documented so far about this feature. So it is not there. I will keep an eye if i heard anything about having this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not currently supported.  This functionality will be added (i.e. it is absolutely planned - see note below), and like AAD Graph API, it'll support deltas on Users, Groups and organizational Contacts. When we do expose sync/deltas for these entities through the O365 unified API, the syntax *may* change a little from what differential query looks like with AAD Graph API.  We'll be certain to document this, and update you when we have more information.  I'm afraid I don't have a timeline for this, but I hope it'll happen sometime soon.

For the O365 unified API, it is a principle/goal of ours to expose the same capabilities and functionalities as is currently available through the individual APIs (and more - like the Office groups).

Hope this helps,